# Fill a column with one of four date columns based on another R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a DF with 5 columns like so;

```
A  B  Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4
1       x     NA    NA    NA
2      NA     y     NA    NA
3      NA    NA     z     NA  
4      NA    NA    NA     f
```

I want to use the dplyr package and the case_when() function to state something like this

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(B = case_when(
     A == 1 ~ B == Date1,
     A == 2 ~ B == Date2,
     A == 3 ~ B == Date3,
     A == 4 ~ B == Date4))
```

Essentially based on the value of A I would like to fill B with one of 4 date columns.

A is of class character, B and the Date are all class Date.

Problem is when I apply this to the dataframe it simply doesn't work. It returns NAs and changes the class of B to boolean. I am using R version 4.1.2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `case_when` syntax is wrong, we don't do `==` in it, just `A == 1 ~ Date1` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are superior, but if you must use your current code for the actual application, the corrected version is:

```
df %>%
  mutate(B = case_when(
    A == 1 ~ Date1,
    A == 2 ~ Date2,
    A == 3 ~ Date3,
    A == 4 ~ Date4))
```

Output:

```
# A B Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4
# 1 x     x  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
# 2 y  <NA>     y  <NA>  <NA>
# 3 z  <NA>  <NA>     z  <NA>
# 4 f  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `coalesce()` to find first non-missing element.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(B = coalesce(!!!df[-1]))

#   A Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 B
# 1 1     x  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> x
# 2 2  <NA>     y  <NA>  <NA> y
# 3 3  <NA>  <NA>     z  <NA> z
# 4 4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     f f
```

The above code is just a shortcut of

```r
df %>%
  mutate(B = coalesce(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4))
```

---

If the `B` needs to be filled based on the value of `A`, then here is an idea with `c_across()`:

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(B = c_across(starts_with("Date"))[A]) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#       A Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 B    
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 x     NA    NA    NA    x    
# 2     2 NA    y     NA    NA    y    
# 3     3 NA    NA    z     NA    z    
# 4     4 NA    NA    NA    f     f
```

Comment: I do not feel like it's the correct answer, since OP's `case_when` stated that if `A` equals to 1, fill `B` with `Date1`, it didn't really say that we should fill `B` with the only non-missing value (your answer assumes that's only one non-missing value per `A`)

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, you want diagonal values from columns with `Date`, you can use `diag`:

```r
df$B <- diag(as.matrix(df[grepl("Date", colnames(df))]))
#[1] "x" "y" "z" "f"
```

---

Other answers (if you want to coalesce):

- With `max`:

```r
df$B <- apply(df[2:5], 1, \(x) max(x, na.rm = T))
```

- With `c_across`:

```r
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(B = max(c_across(Date1:Date4), na.rm = T))
```

output

```r
  A Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 B
1 1     x  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> x
2 2  <NA>     y  <NA>  <NA> y
3 3  <NA>  <NA>     z  <NA> z
4 4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     f f
```

Comment: I do not feel like it's the correct answer, since OP's `case_when` stated that if `A` equals to 1, fill `B` with `Date1` etc, it didn't really say that we should fill `B` with the `max` of the  non-missing values

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: That is correct, the B needed to be filled based on the value of A. See the answer jpsmith provided below where he corrected my code.